# if minute is less than 60 then remove hour part from result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a function like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[testfunctionstacknew] (@dec NUMERIC(18, 2)) RETURNS Varchar(50) 
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE
 @hour decimal(18,2),
      @Mns decimal(18,2),
      @second decimal(18,3)

 DECLARE @Average  Varchar(50) 
select @hour=CONVERT(int,@dec/60/60)
 SELECT @Mns = convert(int, (@dec / 60) - (@hour * 60 ));
 select @second=@dec % 60;

 SELECT @Average = 
       convert(varchar(9), convert(int, @hour)) + ':' +
      -- right('00' + convert(decimal(10,0), convert(decimal(18,2), @hour)), 2) + ':' +
    right('00' + convert(decimal(10,0), convert(decimal(18,2), @Mns)), 2) + ':' +
    right('00' + CONVERT(decimal(10,0), convert(varchar(10), @second)), 6)
 RETURN @Average       

END
```

and i have a stored procedure like this:

```
select   dbo.testfunctionstacknew(
            convert(decimal(10,1),
                avg(convert(numeric(18,2), datediff(ss, t.dtime, t.PAICdate  ))))

        ) as Avgparkingtime  from (select top 10 * from transaction_tbl where locid=6 and dtime >= getdate()-1 order by transactID desc ) t
```

while executing stored procedure if the average time is less than 60 minutes i am getting result like this:

```
Avgparkingtime  :
0:25:33
```

if the average time is less than 60 minutes then i dont want to get zero in front of minutes,,(this time only need to show minutes and seconds)..only hour need to show if the minutes is greater than 60 minutes...how i can do this? what changes i have to make in my function ?? any help is very appreciable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the part where you build the formatted string like this:

```
SELECT @Average = 
   case
   when convert(int, @hour) <> 0 then convert(varchar(9), convert(int, @hour)) + ':'
   else ''
   end +   
   right('00' + convert(decimal(10,0), convert(decimal(18,2), @Mns)), 2) + ':' +
   right('00' + CONVERT(decimal(10,0), convert(varchar(10), @second)), 6)
```

Comment: Great! Please remember to mark it as an answer when possible!

Comment: sir,,i have one more doubt here,,can i ask?

Comment: if we have 1 hour now showing 1,instead of this i have to show 01.and if have 5 minutes showing 5,instead of that i have to show 05..

Comment: Use this - `RIGHT('00'+CAST(columnname AS VARCHAR(2)),2)`. This will show values less than 10 with a leading zero.

Comment: while i am updating i am getting error:Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.